# rails next/prev record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I saw a lot of the same solution for finding next/previous records, but I have a different case.

In my db there are some posts (6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1) and they have `default_scope` for sticked posts: `default_scope :order => 'sticky DESC'`
and if 4's post would be sticked, it would be at first place (4, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1...)

If I'll search next post like this: `record.where('created_at > ?', @post.created_at).first`, it would be 3, not `nil`, because first of all it searches by `created_at` and then ordering by `sticky` column.

How can I find first/next posts with this `default_scope`?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abe38 example

Answer (score 1):

Do you still want to take the default scope into account when finding the "next" record?

If not, use

```
Post.unscoped.where(...).first
```

If yes, you could consider changing your default scope like so:

```
default_scope :order => ['sticky DESC', 'created_at ASC']
```

On a general note, using default scopes should be prevented if possible. They can/will be a nightmare for maintenance later on. It is recommended to use scopes only if required.